# Really cool JS tools: does anybody know what this is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very cool JS components: http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/40664031/ns/us_news-crime_and_courts/

Check out the icons next to the vertical scrollbar in your browser, and the expanding 'sharing' toolbar at the bottom.

Does anybody know if these are publicly available components? Has anybody seen these before?

Edit: I'm talking about:

1. The way the sections in the bottom bar expand into tabs to show more controls. Try clicking on "Login and settings", for example.
2. The way the links near the scrollbar take you to the respective sections. Very cool tool to aid user discovery in a long page.

Comment: disqus is something you can integrate with your existing site for discussions..  having icon layers on floating on top of your page is nothing new - just some css and javascript... where are the cool JS components?

Comment: The cool thing is that the icons are vertically positioned in relation to the corresponding sections, so the icon is positioned where the scrollbar lands when the anchor is targeted. You could probably do that by comparing page height and anchor location to viewport height to determine the icon location.

Comment: Although the icons don't change position when the browser is resized.

Comment: it looks like it's just icons attached next to the scrollbar... but you can click them to #anchor the general sections of the page, i.e., article, discussion, etc. it's just putting a static layer on top of a page with click-able image buttons.

Comment: What about the bottom bar? Try clicking on any of the section, and it expands to show the controls...pretty cool!

Comment: They are cool ideas, but technically not difficult to achieve. Props to msnbc for good execution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was intrigued by the scroll markers used for jumping around the page so I made a start at replicating the functionality in a plugin:

https://github.com/sj26/jquery.scrollmarkers

It's definitely not pretty yet, but it's a start.

Comment: Awesome work! Works great! Haven't tested across browsers, but it's definitely a great start!

Answer (score 1):

Its a private library built by **Krux Digital, Inc.**

I dug into the source of **http://cdn.krxd.net/krux.js**

Its ajax tabs..

Also, you can have a bar fixed at bottom of page simply by using

```
position:fixed
```

property in css, then in the div at bottom, impliment jQuery.tabs, and for each tab load data via ajax. Wont be that difficult. and if MSN has implemented it, they would have surely spent a lot of time on it